# Directus - AWS S3 Upload - error message: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

Tags: amazon-s3, directus

I just set up directus with s3 storage like this: https://docs.directus.io/extensions/storage-adapters.html#core-adapters

It seems to be working: but there is one issue:

[image]

When I upload an image, it gives me an error:  `Cannot set property "value" of undefined`
But when I refresh the page, all is done and it seems to be fine. The files are on s3 and I can see it in my admin panel. But the error message and the need to refresh the page sucks - especially when it comes to give it to my clients.

Is it possible that this could be a bug in the source code of directus?
But when its like that, why I am the only person having this issue ... ?

Here are my config details:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug... perhaps related to a migrations issue (which would be why it's not seen by more people). You could open a ticket on GitHub and the developers will check it out. Just try to make sure it's not a config issue first. :)

Comment: Ok, u mean it could be that there were other images inside the database and directus wanted to migrate the database and this failed at some point because of maybe a nullable reference.
Then when uploading this field is not created - this would explane the "cannot set property 'value' of undefined".

Comment: I will try a fresh installation - maybe u are right.